# How to deal with 2 years old climbing the cot and refuse to sleep?

Tags: toddler, sleep, crying, twins

Our 2 years old twin girls used to sleep in their cots since they were 6 months and it was completely fine. From time to time there were some sleep regressions which didn't last for more than a couple of days and were easy to handle.

This time, and because they got older, one of the girls found out a way to climb the cot and jump! So, once we put her in bed she starts crying and when we leave she starts screaming then jumps out of the cot.

We tried adjusting the cot to a higher level with no luck, the little monkey can still develop some techniques to escape.
Her sister of course panics and start crying loudly too.

The room door is closed, so once we see her jumping we go back and put her in bed. It doesn't work unless we stay beside the bed until she sleeps. Sometimes even we sleep on the ground until she fells asleep.

We are not sure if that technique would lead us somewhere or she will get used to us sharing her room and staying until she sleeps. Because later around 4am she wakes up and repeats it and we have to go and stay until she sleeps and this time it takes longer.

Should we move from cot to bed? And if so, should we then leave her and close the door and when she gives up crying she goes back to her bed easily and sleep?
What if she can open the door? I believe that she may find a way to do so as well specially when she is angry.

Please let me know if this is normal and what techniques did you use?
Thanks

---

Update 1 - Good news

I have tried for a week to stay on the ground beside them until they sleep and every day I move further until I was sitting outside the room. Asked their mum to leave it for me because one of the girls are so attached to her and seems to be having separation anxiety so she doesn't even stay in bed even when her mum is sitting.
However, that technique didn't work 100% and they keep their eyes on the door to see me which sometimes made them worried I am leaving at any time. Also, when they wake up at night and don't see me they cry loudly and one of the girls jumps for the cot.

Two days ago, I put them in bed and left the room and closed the door. They started screaming and the girl started climbing to jump. For almost 1 hour, I was watching them on the monitor and once I see her leaving the cot I go inside, put her back in bed and say it is time to sleep and if you need something we are at next room.
She didn't like that at the first until she gave up after 1 hour and slept.
Last night, we put them in bed and they didn't even cry! First time on 10 days to sleep more than 5 hours continuously

Hopefully today they sleep as well and understand that it is pointless to leave their bed.

I also bought the bed side rail to open the sides but when they slept well yesterday I decided to wait so I don't confuse them.

I will keep you updated..

Comment: What have you tried? Do the twins sleep more soundly if they sleep in the bed with you or do they still wake at night?

Comment: Hi Angela, I have just updated the post. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

If they can't sleep safely in a cot, then they can't sleep in a cot.  Get them real beds.  For a few nights when they go to sleep, lights out everywhere, so they don't think they are missing out on any fun.  If they leave bed, put them back right away silently.  As little interaction as possible.  If they are used to you staying in the room, there are a couple of techniques.  1) slowly move your chair farther and farther away from them, out the door, over the course of a few weeks 2) tell your kids that you have to attend to something, and come back a minute later.  Praise them for waiting so nicely, and keep leaving for a bit longer at a time.

I would advise against screen time prior to bed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this won't be too difficult. I have a 3 year old and she does similar behaviors. What I do is I go to my room, and lay down while watching his/her favorite show or movie. I would try and cuddle them for at least a good 25 minutes( that is how long the episodes are on my little girl' favorite show) If that doesn't work, either do another episode, or lay down with them on the cot and have your partner read a 5 min story of their choice (or sing to them). However, some nights she would wake up and need to go to the restroom. I would lay down next to them untill they fall asleep. Hope this helps your little ones.

Comment: I'm not sure this fully answers the question. In the OP, the querent is in a situation with twin girls. Can you expand your answer to expand that dynamic?